# How can I fix this terminal problem with Python?

Tags: python

I could not run Python on my terminal and I got this error message.

```
Nicks-MBP:~ mfi$ source activate PythonData
Could not find conda environment: PythonData
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

Nicks-MBP:~ mfi$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/mfi/anaconda3
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a terminal problem, but a problem with conda, or how you are invoking it. Try "base".

Comment: The environment `PythonData` does not exist, you have to create it first via `conda create`. The `base` environment is the "main" installation root.

Comment: @filmor is right, just create a new environment with `conda create -n PythonData python=3 -y` and activate it with `source activate PythonData`.